# List referencing a second List in C#

Tags: c#

I have a single class that contains two lists of user defined types, Category and Attribute. I'm trying to get a component of an Attribute to refer to a component of a category.

My Category list looks like this

```
private static List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        var categories = new List<Category> {
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = "Chip Life Cycle"
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 2,
                CategoryName = "Abstraction"
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 3,
                CategoryName = "Properties"
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryID = 4,
                CategoryName = "Location"
            },
        };

        return categories;
    }
```

And here is my attribute list. Each attribute has a CategoryID, I want the next thing, CategoryName to be able to lookin the categories list, find the matching CategoryID and take the CategoryName. How do I do that?

```
private static List<Attribute> GetAttributes()
    {
        var Attributes = new List<Attribute> {
            new Attribute
            {
                AttributeID = 1,
                AttributeName = "Specification",
                Description = "Insertion",
                ImagePath="one.png",
                F_in = 0,
                F_out = 3,
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = **WHAT HERE?**
           },
            new Attribute 
            {
                AttributeID = 2,
                AttributeName = "Design",
                Description = "Insertion",
                ImagePath="two.png",
                F_in = 1,
                F_out = 2,
                CategoryID = 2,
                CategoryName = **WHAT HERE?**
           },
           new Attribute
            {
                AttributeID = 3,
                AttributeName = "Clock Grid",
                Description = "Location",
                ImagePath="thirty_three.png",
                F_in = 16,
                F_out = 0,
                CategoryID = 4
                CategoryName = **WHAT HERE?**
            },
        };
        return Attributes;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just reference `Category` from `Attribute`?

Comment: If your custom `Category` class really only has two properties, perhaps it would be better to use an `enum` instead of a custom class? Making it an `enum` guarantees that `1` always has the same `"Chip Life Cycle"` whereas with your current implementation, you could concievably instantiate two different Categories with the same IDs and different Names.

Comment: @OndrejTucny:  That seems best. This seems like a relational database schema transplanted into c#.

Answer (score 4):

You are "denormalizing" some information from Category into Attribute.  Specifically, you are repeating the CategoryID and CategoryName. Instead, just reference Category itself, e.g.

```
new Attribute
{
    AttributeID = 1,
    AttributeName = "Specification",
    Description = "Insertion",
    ImagePath="one.png",
    F_in = 0,
    F_out = 3,
    Category = category1, // category1 is an instance of Category
 },
```

You can then get at e.g. the first attribute's category name like:

```
string name = GetAttributes().First().Category.Name;
```

Comment: I was gonna offer use of `LINQ` but this answer is much better.